binding elements to pseudo events without using eval
I have a big legacy web app that needs to be made CSP (content security policy) compliant.  It is full of inline event handlers, eg
onclick="alert('hello')"

I am trying to write some js which will scan the page on load and replace all these inline handlers with dynamically assigned handlers, eg
var oc = $("#btn").attr("onclick");
$("#btn").on("click", function(){oc});

This obviously wont work, I don't know what each inline event is ahead of time, so it needs to be added as a string.  Trouble is there is no way of doing this I can find which is CSP compliant.  I tried replace all the real inline handlers with pseudo events, eg onclick becomes zclick , then extracting these plsurdo handlers  and creating real dynamic handlers:
var oc = $("#btn").attr("zclick");
var func = Function(oc);
btn.on("click", func);

but CSP caught this as "unsafe eval".  I tried discovering how angular does it, as in how it converts ng-click to real onclick events but it seems to extreme low level custom compiling or some such.  Does any one have any ideas as to how I may achieve this?

What exactly does "needs to be made CSP (content security policy) compliant" mean? You will either need to allow inline event handlers in your policy (which is still better than no CSP at all), or you need to do the hard work of rewriting the legacy app not to use them any longer. There is no simple script that will circumvent a strict CSP and work with your current HTML code.

the client has added a strict csp header to iis, no inline css, no inline event handlers.  I already started the grunt work of moving everything to css/js files but I thought if angular can magically turn ngclick in onclick there must be a way anyone can do it.

https://github.com/Siubaak/sval

"if angular can magically turn ngclick in onclick"... that's not what it does at all

If CSP is in the IIS header, then it will block the "onclick=before you can run your js to read the onclick.  You *might* get away with$("button").attr("onclick", function() { return $(this).attr("myclick") });` and change all the onclick= to myclick= in the src, example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47q2xthu/

no, csp catches this.

Since you say we can't use eval() we can instead create a string of JS with all our event listeners and dynamically load it as script...
const Events=[
 'abort','afterprint','animationcancel','animationend','animationiteration','animationstart','audioprocess','auxclick','beforeprint','beforeunload','blur','broadcast','canplay','canplaythrough','change',
 'CheckboxStateChange','checking','click','close','complete','compositionend','compositionstart','compositionupdate','contextmenu','copy','cut','dblclick','downloading','drag','dragend','dragenter',
 'dragleave','dragover','dragstart','drop','durationchange','emptied','ended','error','focus','focusin','focusout','fullscreenchange','fullscreenerror','hashchange','input','invalid','keydown',
 'keypress','keyup','load','loadeddata','loadedmetadata','loadend','loadstart','message','mousedown','mouseenter','mouseleave','mousemove','mouseout','mouseover','mouseup','noupdate','obsolete',
 'offline','online','open','pagehide','pageshow','paste','pause','play','playing','pointerlockchange','pointerlockerror','popstate','progress','RadioStateChange','ratechange','readystatechange','reset',
 'resize','scroll','seeked','seeking','select','show','stalled','storage','submit','suspend','timeout','timeupdate','transitioncancel','transitionend','transitionrun','transitionstart','unhandledrejection',
 'unload','updateready','ValueChange','volumechange','waiting','wheel'];


var E=document.querySelectorAll('*'), A='', Z='', S='';


for(let x=0; x<E.length; x++){

  // In the next line we need to create an ID if not found, using a random number

 if(E[x].hasAttribute('id')===false){E[x].id='e'+RandomNum(99999);} 

 for(let y=0; y<Events.length; y++){

  A='on'+Events[y];

  if(E[x].hasAttribute(A)){

   Z=E[x].getAttribute(A);

   E[x].removeAttribute(A);

   S+=E[x].id.toString()+'.addEventListener(\''+A.slice(2)+'\',function(e){'+Z.replace(/'/g,'"')+'},false);';

}}}


var N=document.createElement('script');

N.type='text/javascript';

// N.onload=function(){alert('Loaded!');}; // We don't actually need this

N.text=S;

document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(N);

Notes:
1: Random number generating function not supplied.
2: The whole thing is totally untested code but it does compile.
3: An interesting challenge, thanks for the opportunity to exercise my brain.

this won''t work because inline script blocks are blocked by CSP

Firstly, I agree 100% that this job should be automated so keep persevering in this direction.
However, eval() would be useless (actually catastrophic) because it doesn’t convert strings to code... it only EXECUTES strings as code, so you’d have tons of code suddenly firing away like Chinese firecrackers! :)
But anyway, we don’t need eval() for this job... we can always assemble a string of JS (lots of event listeners basically in string format) and load it dynamically as script as the code below does.
In the worst case scenario, if the loading was to fail we can still extract the string of all the event listeners (by saving it in a textarea) to save us from all that typing in the event that it has to be done manually... so keep going it’s a win-win!
Alright, so here’s an updated version that eliminates the need for a random number function and moves the ID creation line further down where it should be...
const Events=[
 'abort','afterprint','animationcancel','animationend','animationiteration','animationstart','audioprocess','auxclick','beforeprint','beforeunload','blur','broadcast','canplay','canplaythrough','change',
 'CheckboxStateChange','checking','click','close','complete','compositionend','compositionstart','compositionupdate','contextmenu','copy','cut','dblclick','downloading','drag','dragend','dragenter',
 'dragleave','dragover','dragstart','drop','durationchange','emptied','ended','error','focus','focusin','focusout','fullscreenchange','fullscreenerror','hashchange','input','invalid','keydown',
 'keypress','keyup','load','loadeddata','loadedmetadata','loadend','loadstart','message','mousedown','mouseenter','mouseleave','mousemove','mouseout','mouseover','mouseup','noupdate','obsolete',
 'offline','online','open','pagehide','pageshow','paste','pause','play','playing','pointerlockchange','pointerlockerror','popstate','progress','RadioStateChange','ratechange','readystatechange','reset',
 'resize','scroll','seeked','seeking','select','show','stalled','storage','submit','suspend','timeout','timeupdate','transitioncancel','transitionend','transitionrun','transitionstart','unhandledrejection',
 'unload','updateready','ValueChange','volumechange','waiting','wheel'];


var E=document.querySelectorAll('*'), A='', Z='', S='';


for(let x=0; x<E.length; x++){

 for(let y=0; y<Events.length; y++){

  A='on'+Events[y];

  if(E[x].hasAttribute(A)){

   if(E[x].hasAttribute('id')===false){E[x].id='e'+(x*y);} 

   Z=E[x].getAttribute(A);

   E[x].removeAttribute(A);

   S+=E[x].id.toString()+'.addEventListener(\''+A.slice(2)+'\',function(e){'+Z.replace(/'/g,'"')+'},false);';

}}}


var N=document.createElement('script');

N.type='text/javascript'; N.text=S;

document.head.appendChild(N);


Please edit your previous answer instead of posting a new one

ChatGPT smelling here.

@Bergi different user, same name

this doesn't work, csp blocks inline scripts.
